# SQL Trigger Error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am creating a trigger for my database but I am getting an error that I can see to get rid of. the trigger is run before an intersect and is used to check if p_day is in the days of the week, if it is it will say valid day and if not it will raise an exception. I am getting an error on the raise exception line. Can anyone help?

this is my trigger

```
create or replace trigger DAY_CHECK
BEFORE INSERT ON AD_SLOT
DECLARE
  p_day VARCHAR(20);
  NOTVALID EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
SELECT DAY_OF_WEEK INTO p_day  FROM AD_SLOT;
IF p_day IN ('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday') then
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALID DAY');
ELSE
RAISE EXCEPTION;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NOTVALID THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT A VALID DAY');
END;
```

this is the error i am getting

```
Error(11,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol "EXCEPTION" was ignored.
```

Comment: Instead of `RAISE EXCEPTION` I think you wanted `RAISE NOTVALID`. Try that and see if it helps. Share and enjoy.

Comment: thanks Bob that has fixed it for me!

Comment: I assume this is a homework assignment and not a real issue.  You wouldn't use a trigger to enforce this sort of thing, you'd use a check constraint in the real world.  Even for an assignment, you'd need a row-level trigger unless you happen to be able to guarantee that the table always has exactly 1 row in it (which could only have been inserted before the trigger was created).

Comment: nope not homework or an assignment, I am just trying to learn more about databases by making my own on and implementing different things.